# TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean: using both SslContextSupport and SocketFactorySupport

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm using TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean (for client, non-NIO connections) and would like to modify my SSL Socket connections in 2 ways:

1/ **use TLS1.2 protocol only**
I do this by calling *TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean.setSslContextSupport()* and providing a *DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport* object with TLSv1.2 protocol set.

and

2/ **set a socket connect timeout**
I do this by calling *TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean.setSocketFactorySupport()* and providing a customised subclass of *TcpSocketFactorySupport* which creates the socket and then applies timeout in connect call.  This technique is documented [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/TCP-Socket-Connection-Techniques).

I have both working independently, but can't get them working together.  Looking at the TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean code it's clear that the obtainSocketFactorySupport() method will only select one.  I therefore think my approach is incorrect.  Can anyone offer any guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I've got it working by combining into a single SocketFactorySupport class that subclasses *DefaultTcpNetSSLSocketFactorySupport* and then use with the *TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean.setSocketFactorySupport()* call.  My subclass looks like this, pass *DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport* (with protocol set) and timeout into the constructor:

```
public class MySSLSocketFactorySupport extends DefaultTcpNetSSLSocketFactorySupport {

    private final int connectTimeout;

    public MySSLSocketFactorySupport(TcpSSLContextSupport sslContextSupport, int connectTimeout) {
        super(sslContextSupport);
        this.connectTimeout = connectTimeout;
    }

    @Override
    public ServerSocketFactory getServerSocketFactory() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This does not support server sockets");
    }

    @Override
    public SocketFactory getSocketFactory() {
        return new PostilionSocketFactory();
    }

    private class PostilionSocketFactory extends SocketFactory {

        private final SocketFactory delegate = MySSLSocketFactorySupport.super.getSocketFactory();

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
            return delegate.createSocket();
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
            Socket socket = this.delegate.createSocket();
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), connectTimeout);
            return socket;
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
            Socket socket = this.delegate.createSocket();
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), connectTimeout);
            return socket;
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
            Socket socket = this.delegate.createSocket();
            socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(localHost, localPort));
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), connectTimeout);
            return socket;
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
            Socket socket = this.delegate.createSocket();
            socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(localAddress, localPort));
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(address, port), connectTimeout);
            return socket;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: So, your solution is correct. When you provide a custom `TcpSocketFactorySupport`, the `SslContext` must be supplied in that one.